# Bi-Lipschitz extension

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

> Given a bi-Lipschitz homeomorphism
> $\Phi:\mathbb{B}^n(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}^n$, (that is a bi-Lipschitz map onto the image), can one find a bi-Lipschitz homeomorphism $\Psi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
> $$
> \Psi|_{\mathbb{B}^n(0,\frac{1}{2})}=\Phi|_{\mathbb{B}^n(0,\frac{1}{2})}\ \ ?
> $$

It follows from the planar bi-Lipschitz Schoenflies theorem **[T]** that
when $n=2$, the answer is yes since you can actually extend $\Phi$ from $\mathbb{B}^2(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ in a bi-Lipschitz manner, but in higher dimensions it is not possible to extend from $\mathbb{B}^n(0,1)$, and this is why I am asking about extension from a smaller ball.

Thickening of the Fox-Artin arc creates a domain $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is bi-Lipschitz homeomorphic to $\mathbb{B}^3(0,1)$, but no bi-Lipschitz homeomorphism $\Phi:\mathbb{B}^3\to\Omega$ can be extended to a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^3$. This was observed by Fred Gehring in 1968, but details were not provided. Details are provided in Theorem 3.7 in **[M]**.

**[M] Martin, G.:** [Quasiconformal and bi-Lipschitz homeomorphisms, uniform domains and the quasihyperbolic metric.](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1985-292-01/S0002-9947-1985-0805959-2/S0002-9947-1985-0805959-2.pdf) *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* 292 (1985), 169–191.

**[T] Tukia, P.:** [The planar Schönflies theorem for Lipschitz maps.](https://afm.journal.fi/article/view/134368) *Ann. Acad. Sci. Fenn. Ser. A I Math.* 5 (1980), no. 1, 49–72.

Comment: I don't have an explicit construction, but can the Alexander horned sphere be realized as the image of the 2-sphere under a bilipschitz map of a 3-ball?

Comment: Did you check “Hyperbolic geometry and homeomorphisms” by Sullivan. (I think your statement should follow from this paper, but if I remember right it is not easy to extract.)

Comment: @RobertYoung I am not sure about the horned sphere, but I think there are related examples due to Tukia and Vaisala that show that you cannot extend a bi-Lipschitz homeomorphism from the ball. However, I want the bi-Lipschitz homeomorphisms to coincide with the given one on a smaller ball, so I am not extending it from the entire ball.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz Oops, I missed that when I read the question.  In that case, it seems more likely.  Do you want the Lipschitz constant of $\Psi$ to be bounded in terms of the Lipschitz constant of $\Phi$?

Comment: @RobertYoung Any Lipschitz constant would be okay, but if one could get a Lipschitz constant comparable to that of $\Phi$ that would be even better.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin I think you are right about Sullivan's paper. However, his paper contains ideas, but no proofs. I am checking some papers by Tukia and Vaisala where more details should be provided. I am interested in the problem again, but for reasons different than before.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz did you find an appropriate reference? --- if yes, then share please.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin I am working on that. I hope I will have a satisfactory answer soon. I will let you know.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin I added an answer and a reference to Tukia-Vaisala's paper. Sullivan's paper is annoying due to lack of any details. Tukia and Vaisala tried to understand it. They could add details to some of the arguments (in another paper), but for other statements in Sullivan's paper they used "leap of faith".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following result answers the question by providing a locally bi-Lipschitz extension.

> **Theorem.** Given a bi-Lipschitz homeomorphism
> $\Phi:\mathbb{B}^n(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}^n$, (that is a bi-Lipschitz map onto the image), one can find a locally bi-Lipschitz homeomorphism $\Psi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
> $$
> \Psi|_{\mathbb{B}^n(0,\frac{1}{2})}=\Phi|_{\mathbb{B}^n(0,\frac{1}{2})}.
> $$

This result is a straightforward consequence of the Theorem 5.10 in [TV]. If we regard $\mathbb{B}^n(0,1)$ as a subset of $\mathbb{S}^n$ (stereographic projection + one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^n$), then $\Phi$ can be extended from $\mathbb{B}^n(0,\frac{1}{2})$ to a bi-Lipschitz map of $\mathbb{S}^n$. Such a map gives a locally bi-Lipschitz map of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Theorem 5.10 is a version of the generalized Schoenflies theorem for bi-Lipschitz maps.

**Remark.** I think it is possible to find not only a locally bi-Lipschitz, but a bi-Lipschitz extension. Argument would be the same as above, with the only difference that we would place at the north poles (from which we have stereographic projections) points there the extension and its inverse are differentiable. But, I have to think about this argument a bit more.

**[TV] Tukia, P.; Väisälä, J.:** [Lipschitz and quasiconformal approximation and extension.](https://www.acadsci.fi/mathematica/Vol06/vol06pp303-342.pdf) *Ann. Acad. Sci. Fenn. Ser. A I Math.* 6 (1981), no. 2, 303–342 (1982).

Answer (score 2):

Let me describe a baby case of Sulivan's construction which is beautiful.

Assume I have a homeomorphism $h$ from pentagon to itself that sends each side to itself.

Let us assume that the pentagon has right angles in the conformal disc model of Lobachevsky plane. Extend the map $h$ to the disc applying reflections in the sides of pentagon, so the obtained map $\tilde h$ commutes with and any reflection in a side of pentagon.

Note that $\tilde h$ is bi-Lipschitz and it is identity on the boundary of the disc. So we can extend $\tilde h$ by identity map outside of disc.

It is problematic to do the same for general $h$ and higher dimensions, but all this seem to be solved by Sullivan.